# tcsh prompt acting weird

Tags: linux, tcsh

I've got this line my .cshrc.user (using tcsh)

```
set prompt = "%{\033[36m%}%m%{\033[32m]%}{`echo $CLEARCASE_ROOT | cut -d / -f 3`}%{\033[0m%}> "
```

And it's working nicely with the colors and everything. But when I try this:

```
echo $prompt
```

It just gives me either

```
Missing ].
```

or

```
Missing }.
```

depending on wether a clearcase view is set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say that the variable CLEARCASE_ROOT has a `[` or a `{` character. Try quoting the variable when performing the echo? i.e.:

```
echo "$prompt"
```

Comment: cool - Didn't know about the :q modifier will keep it in mind